# Regular expressions - replacement of url

Tags: php, regex

I have in my string $content many url:

```
<a href="https://domain/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/sample-Wokal-2.jpg"><img class="alignright size-full wp-image-6608" src="https://domain/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/sample-Wokal-2.jpg" alt="sample Wokal 2" width="933" height="617" /></a>

<a href="https://domain/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/sample-lato-123.jpg"><img class="alignright size-full wp-image-6608" src="https://domain/uploads/2014/01/sample-lato-123.jpg" alt="sample lato 123" width="933" height="617" /></a>
```

etc

Is it possible replace all links to:
- https://domain/files/sample-lato-123.jpg ,
- https://domain/files/sample-Wokal-2.jpg ,

etc?

How to do it?
I tried str_replace - but I have different types of links and I do not know how to replace them. I do not know about regular expressions :(

Please help.

Comment: If `$content` is just HTML/XML then convert it to a DOM object and use XPath to target and modify links.

Comment: I can not do this. Could you write me how to do it?

Comment: No. I believe in you. Read https://stackoverflow.com/a/1744154/2191572 to get started. If you have a specific issue then come back and ask for help.

Comment: Not at all, you should use preg_match :and preg_replace

Comment: Forgive my bogus answer, i deleted it. If you really want to match URLs via regex, maybe this thread might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809401/what-is-a-good-regular-expression-to-match-a-url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex which does lookarounds to ensure the string that needs to be replaced is indeed the one we want,

```
(?<=domain).*?(?=sample)
```

and replace with

```
/files/
```

Here is sample PHP code,

```
$str = '<a href="https://domain/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/sample-Wokal-2.jpg"><img class="alignright size-full wp-image-6608" src="https://domain/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/sample-Wokal-2.jpg" alt="sample Wokal 2" width="933" height="617" /></a>\n<a href="https://domain/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/sample-lato-123.jpg"><img class="alignright size-full wp-image-6608" src="https://domain/uploads/2014/01/sample-lato-123.jpg" alt="sample lato 123" width="933" height="617" /></a>';
echo preg_replace('/(?<=domain).*?(?=sample)/', '/files/', $str);
```

Prints,

```
<a href="https://domain/files/sample-Wokal-2.jpg"><img class="alignright size-full wp-image-6608" src="https://domain/files/sample-Wokal-2.jpg" alt="sample Wokal 2" width="933" height="617" /></a>\n<a href="https://domain/files/sample-lato-123.jpg"><img class="alignright size-full wp-image-6608" src="https://domain/files/sample-lato-123.jpg" alt="sample lato 123" width="933" height="617" /></a>
```

Let me know if this works fine for you.